# Need AutoSuggest code sample with multi line like Facebook

Tags: c#, asp.net, autosuggest

I Need a AutoSuggest with multiline like Facebook for asp.net + c# web application.

Suggestion items w'll be multiline (multiline for every Item) as bellow.

---

---------------------
**School Name 1**
City 1
---------------------
**School Name 2**
City 1
---------------------
**School Name 3**
City 2
---------------------

---

I've tried to use ConvincingMail.AdvancedAutoSuggest.dll. It's working fine on LocalHost but not working on WebServer.

Please tell me a solution

Answer (score 1):

You want the jQuery autocomplete plugin. Get it from [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete).

It's very easy to use. You just tell it which events it needs to fire on selected and when formatting each item. It hooks into a Generic Handler as well so can be completely async with server side code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the [AJAX Toolkit AutoSuggest](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx). And just use {SchoolName}<br />{CityName} as the data text field.